# How big can CMS database be?

Tags: php, mysql

I am planing to build a simple CMS (with PHP) for my own educational needs and I ran into a problem with design as I have never encountered this in any book or tutorial. 
If I wanted to let used mess around the colors for example. How do I do that? The only idea I had was make a database with basically all such a options and then echo them to the site as normal CSS. But thet would mean it would load from DB every single time someone visits the webasite. It seems to me like it could overload the website. But again, I have never encountered such a problem. Or is there a way of doing this much more easily?

Thanks for every answer!

**EDIT:**
I would like to create a system that enables user to change css via CMS. For example background color, drop-down menu colors, text sizes, fonts and a lot of other stuff  handeled by CSS. Simple customization.
So I was asking 2 questions.

1. How? What system should I use? No book/tutorial I read never covered editing CSS files using PHP so I have no idea how to do that. Or maybe there are better ways of doing it?
2. I had idea how I would store all customisable data. In database I wanted to know how big it can be and whether it would be a problem when posibly tens or maybe even houndreds of variables would be loading to the site.

**EDIT2:**
And btw I never worked with Wordpress or other CMS and I kind of expected that options like what I am looking for are present there, is that true? In my mind such a feature is essential for user inexperienced with computers. But from what I understand from link provided by Sam (http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/), it's not common. It's actually quite complicated thing and might harm performance of the website.

I hope I made my question clear now.

Comment: Toooo big for you :D. A small database (like you are pointing) can handle like 105,000 (MYSQL) or 750,000 (INNODB) requests per second!

Comment: Ok, good to know. And the way I want to store data is correct? Or is there a better way? I see that I look like and idiot for asking such a question, but I really never read about this and all my knowledge comes from books and tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Something like this could help: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has tons of downvotes, but you can cache your database queries. You can also mimic a CSS file using the header type in PHP. See http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

This will allow the browser to cache the CSS file that was generated by PHP & MySQL. This means the database will only be called when the cache expires.

In terms of size you will never reach a limit with what you are describing.

**Update**

These sort of features are a bit unorthodox, using a cached version of the generated CSS file is basically mandatory.

What you can do is include a text editor within the CMS to edit the CSS file, each user can have their own CSS file that overrides the default one if changed. By letting them edit it directly they can change the layout themselves. You can even limit them to only changing colours / font-sizes etc.

Comment: That seems like what I am looking for, but after reading trough the comments under that article, it seems like my problem is more complicated then it looked. I updated my question.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a way of doing it, but it doesnt make it any easier for computer inexperianced users. I had an idea that I could combine both systems. There would be the dynamic one, that would switch on when user starts messing around and in the end outputs classic css file and start using that once user is done with changes. Or maybe I am just overcomplicating it...

Comment: There no easy way of simplifying it, unless they only need to change a couple of values.

The solution would to use the PHP generated CSS but use LESS / SASS that compiles into CSS. That way changing the main theme colours will be able to change the whole layout of the website.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will have a look at it.